# Dynamic Calling Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I've got 2 activities ( MainActivity and CallLayoutActivity) and I've also got 2 layouts (main and layout_for_use).
In layout(main) I have 6 buttons. example: when I press button 3 it show layout color pink or press button 4 show layout color blue.

what I want is I don't want to create 6 CallLayoutActivities and 6 layouts.

Hint

button 1: Mainactivity > CallLayoutActivity > layout color white
button 2: Mainactivity > CallLayoutActivity > layout color black

every button I uses onClickListener and Intent for calling new class

```
Intent i_btn_number = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallLayoutActivity.class);
StartActivity(i_btn_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the button number to CallLayoutActivity through intent and depending on that button number change the color of layout in CallLayoutActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

for ex:

```
if(btn1)
    i_btn_number.putExtra("color","color_here-1";
else if(btn2)
    i_btn_number.putExtra("color","color_here-2";
else if(btn3)
    i_btn_number.putExtra("color","color_here-2";
...
```

in **CallLayoutActivity.java**

```
color = getIntent().getStringExtra("color");
layout.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: it still load the layout the same color. how can i use if statement?

Comment: I've got image name(1,2,3...) in drawable. in CallLayoutActivity i set, img.setImageResource(R.drawable.1). when press button 1 image change to 1. press 2 change to 2. _how can I change image when i press button?_

Comment: In MainActivity  `b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View v) { Intent i_1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallLayoutActivity.class); i_1.putExtra("my_image", "..."); startActivity(i_1); } }); b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { Intent i_2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallLayoutActivity.class); i_2.putExtra("my_image", "..."); startActivity(i_2); } });`   In CallLayoutActivity. `String my_image;  my_image = getIntent().getStringExtra("my_image");  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.1);`